# Node Alias issue in Google?

Tags: drupal, pathauto, drupal-path-aliases

My website pages all show up in Google search results as ***.com/node/#### instead of the alias name.

I need help fixing the naming convention to show up in Google via alias, as they are also listed in the sitemap.xml. I'm not sure if this needs to be fixed from Drupal or through NGINX.

Note that I don't have this issue in Bing.

Comment: yep sure I will accept the answer that will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Also have a look at the questions you've asked earlier ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this can be that Google bots have indexed your urls with `node/nid` formats.

But its weird that you don't have this issue in Bing. The only reason I can think of for this anamoly is that Bing crawled the right urls just by chance or Bing has a rule which says when there are aliases use more meaningful ones(which can't be true for Bing :P)

Anyways go ahead and install http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect module. This should solve your problems as it creates 301 redirects for all you aliased paths which is very SEO friendly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that google found your page while you had aliasses disabled, and Bing found it later when the aliasses were enabled.

If you want them removed you can go to google webmaster tools. http://webmaster.google.com
There you can upload a new sitemap and remove URL's that you no longer use.

Comment: Hi Neograph 
I have uploaded new sitemap but the issue is still there.

Comment: Are the 'wrong' URL's still accessable or do they present a 404 / 301 ? Also adding a sitemap is not enough, you will have to remove all wrong URL's one by one.